# Why is the Tkinter .after() method executing immediately

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a chatbot, and I want an opening message, 'Hi! Thanks for stopping by. Feel free to leave me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible :)', to pop up *after 3 seconds of opening the window.* I tried using the after method but the message posts immediately, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Message Me Here!')
window.configure(background = 'light pink')

class Chatbot:
    def __init__(self, main):
        aFrame = Frame(main)
        aFrame.pack()

        self.chatroom = Text(main, height = 20, width = 35, wrap = 'word')
        self.chatroom.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.message = Entry(main, width = 45)
        self.message.insert(0, 'Enter your message here...')
        self.message.pack()

        self.send_button = Button(main, text = 'Send', command = self.send)
        self.send_button.pack(pady = 5)

    # I want this function to execute 3 seconds after the window is opened
    def first_bot_message(self, first_time = []):
        if first_time == []:
            self.chatroom.insert('end', 'Hi! Thanks for stopping by. Feel free to leave me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible :)') 
            self.chatroom.after(3, self.first_bot_message) 
            first_time.append('Not Empty')
    def send(self):
        the_message = self.message.get()
        self.chatroom.insert('end', the_message)

e = Chatbot(window)

# calling the function 

e.first_bot_message()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because you used `e.first_bot_message()` in the end.

Comment: when should I call the function then? @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: Don't call `e.first_bot_message()`.Use `self.message.after(3000, self.first_bot_message)` in `__init__`.

Comment: Awesome, worked, thank you! Could you explain why I had to put it in the self.message section?

Comment: It is not necessary to put it in the `self.message`.You could also use `main.after(3000, self.first_bot_message)`.

Comment: Just to add on the other responses, .after() takes its first argument as time in milliseconds. .after(3, self.first_bot_message) executes your function after 3 milliseconds.